# How can I edit sudoers file if I have lost permissions despite providing root password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, permissions, command

While working on ubuntu, I have edited sudoers file and allowed myself to run only mkdir, cd command. Now I am unable to execute, install any command. Even visudo is not working despite providing root password. How can I edit sudoers?

Comment: Use a Live-CD .

Comment: `su -` to switch to root (using the root password), correct the mistake. Also, allowing `sudo cd` is a bit useless as that would not do anything.

Comment: Ubuntu installations don't enable the root account by default - however, newer versions often allow at least local users to execute `visudo` via `pkexec`. See for example [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file/73872#73872)